# How to unmerge cells and create a standard dataframe when reading excel file?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I would like to convert this dataframe

[image]

into this dataframe

[image]

So far reading excel the standard way gives me the following result.

```
df = pd.read_excel(folder + 'abcd.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

```
    Unnamed: 0                   Unnamed: 1 T12006      T22006      T32006  \
0   Casablanca                      Global     100    97.27252   93.464538   
1          NaN                  Résidentiel    100   95.883979   92.414063   
2          NaN                  Appartement    100   95.425152   91.674379   
3          NaN                      Maison     100  101.463607  104.039383   
4          NaN                       Villa     100   102.45132  101.996932
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try method .fillna() with parameter method='ffill'. According to the pandas documentation for the ffill method: *ffill: propagate last valid observation forward to next valid backfill*.
So, your code would be like:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

And change name of 0 and 1 columns with this lines:

```
df.columns.values[0] = "City"
df.columns.values[1] = "Type"
```

Comment: Thank you it works great and it saves a lot of manual handling

Comment: The column `df.columns.values[0] = "City"`  is for some reason not recognized when i do `df['City'].unique()` it gives me an error `KeyError: 'City'`. I am not sure why. The same thing happens when I do `print(df['City'])`

Comment: Try this one: df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: "City", df.columns[1]: "Type"},inplace=True)